# Custom theme in ExtJS pointing to wrong image folders

Tags: extjs, compass-sass, theming

I've create a custom theme using Sencha ExtJS and the `compass compile` and `sencha splice` commands.

I have a folder structure as follows:

```
/ext-4.1.0 -- This is where the stock SDK resides
/resources -- copied from the SDK template, as per the instructions
/resources/sass -- This is where my SASS and confif.rb file reside
/resources/css -- This is where compass compiles my my-ext-theme.css
/resources/images/foo/bar.gif -- This is where sencha splice creates my GIFs.
```

The problem is, the newly-compiled `/resources/css/my-ext-theme.css` is referring to all images with the relative paths like `../../ext-4.1.0/resources/themes/images/default/foo/bar.gif`.

Why is my custom theme compiling to refer to the *stock* image folder rather than my *custom* images?

Here are the key  parameters in my `config.rb` file:

```
$ext_path = "../../ext-4.1.0"
sass_path = File.dirname(__FILE__)
css_path = File.join(sass_path, "..", "css")
load File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), $ext_path, 'resources', 'themes')
```

I don't want to pollute my `ext-4.1.0` folder with custom theme files if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the "bug" referred to in the documentation here applies to version 4.1.0, not just to 4.0.7. Changing the `utils.rb` file as described fixed the relative path problem:

http://www.sencha.com/learn/theming/